# Scalene: An exception of type UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, profiler, scalene

I'm trying to run Scalene inside a .ipynb fily in Jupyter with %%scalene and get the following error:

```
Scalene: An exception of type UnicodeEncodeError occurred. Arguments:
('charmap', '\r\n<html>\r\n  <head>\r\n    <title>Scalene</title> ...
```

followed by basically the whole Scalene Github website html code and ending with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marci\anaconda3\envs\wc2022v2_env\lib\site-packages\scalene\scalene_profiler.py", line 1949, in run_profiler
    exit_status = profiler.profile_code(
  File "C:\Users\marci\anaconda3\envs\wc2022v2_env\lib\site-packages\scalene\scalene_profiler.py", line 1781, in profile_code
    Scalene.generate_html(profile_fname=Scalene.__profile_filename, output_fname=Scalene.__profiler_html)
  File "C:\Users\marci\anaconda3\envs\wc2022v2_env\lib\site-packages\scalene\scalene_profiler.py", line 1729, in generate_html
    f.write(rendered_content)
  File "C:\Users\marci\anaconda3\envs\wc2022v2_env\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 79534: character maps to <undefined>
```

Am I right to think it is the website coding that is causing this error? Or is it the browser?

If anything else: what can be done about it?

python 3.8.15

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error related to cp1250. Seems [scalene](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) profiler didn't bother to test national environments. Tried to use `chcp 65001` to set runtime to utf-8, but it didn't help.

My fix was to hack its source "`(...)\scalene\scalene_profiler.py`" at line 1728:
instead of:

```
with open(output_fname, "w") as f:
```

use:

```
with open(output_fname, "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been patched as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74696070/335756. Please install the current version (1.5.20 or later); that should solve your problems. (Also, please post any future issues, if any, on https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene !)

Comment: I have a similar problem, with the latest version of scalene. Your link to github gives error 404.

Comment: Link fixed. Please post an issue with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).